# PouchDB get documents by ID with certain string in them

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I would like to get all documents that contain a certain string in them, I can't seem to find a solution for it..

for example I have the following doc ids

```
vw_10
vw_11
bmw_12
vw_13
bmw_14
volvo_15
vw_16
```

how can I get allDocs with the string vw_ "in" it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [batch fetch API](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_fetch):

```
db.allDocs({startkey: "vm_", endkey: "vm_\ufff0"})
```

Note: `\ufff0` is the highest Unicode character which is used as sentinel to specify ranges for ordered strings.

Comment: thanks for the reply it worked. Can I ask where you got the uff0 part?

Comment: @Scratch. http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/collation.html#raw-collation

Comment: Note: `startkey` and `endkey` only find keys that *begin* with the given sequence. The above function call would not find 'uvw_10'...

Answer (score 5):

You can use PouchDB find plugin API which is way more sophisticated than allDocs IMO for querying. With the PouchDB find plugin, there is a regex search operator which will allow you do exactly this.

```
db.find({selector: {name: {$regext: '/vw_'}}});
```

It's in BETA at the time of writing but we are about to ship a production app with it. That's how stable it has been so far. See https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find for more on Pouch Db Find

Comment: I had to use `$regex` because I got this: `Error: unknown operator "$regext" - should be one of $eq, $lte, $lt, $gt, $gte, $exists, $ne, $in, $nin, $size, $mod, $regex, $elemMatch, $type, $allMatch or $all`.

Comment: @Rehmat he misspelled regex as regext (or maybe the selector name was changed in the past).

Comment: This answers the question, but if someone is interested in a case-insensitive search, replace `'/vw_'` with `RegExp(<string>, "i")`. Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46352649/1276636).

Answer (score 0):

You better have a view with the key you want to search. This ensures that the key is indexed. Otherwise, the search might be too slow.

Comment: You mean something like this vw/10, vw/11, vw/13?